# passing data to child component angular (Data recived from web service not append on child)

Tags: angular, typescript

I am Trying to assign data after service load for better understanding watch the code .

**Service**

```
getcampaigndata(slug: any): Promise<any> {                
     return this.http
                .get('service url'+slug)
                .toPromise()
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

**Parents Component**

```
public slug: string;
public data: any = {};

this.campaign.getcampaigndata(this.slug).subscribe(params => {
      this.data = params;
});
```

**Child Component**

```
import {CampaignComponent} from '../../campaign.component';

constructor(private shared: SharedService,private route:ActivatedRoute,public campaign: CampaignComponent) { };

 ngOnInit() {
     console.log(this.campaign.slug);
     console.log(this.campaign.data);
 }
```

> ```
> **Output** :
> SLUG
> Object{}
> ```

As you can see i have import the `CampaignComponet` on another component its working very good for slug cuz `slug` is assign on runtime but for `data` its not assigned because of http request . Any one have solution of this ?

using `this.data=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentCampaig‌​n'));` instand of *webservice* works fine

Comment: How to pass data from parent component to child component? Since because you get data from service, it's better to load the child component once the data get available. For ex, `<child-tag *ngIf="data.foo" ..></child-tag>`

Comment: @AvinashRaj by importing parent component . i have tried `<child-tag *ngIf="data.foo"></child-tag>` but its works for immidate assignend value . ilike local storage . web service data not assigned through this method

Comment: You have to pass data from parent to child component using `@Input`, I think importing won't work.

Comment: okay lets tried

Answer (score 6):

Use `@Input` decorator to pass data to your child component

```
<child-component [myData]="data"></child-component>
```

And in the `ChildComponent`

```
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() myData;
}
```

And also when `ngOnInit()` is called your passed data is not bound yet. So you need another lifecycle event, `ngOnChanges()` or `ngAfterViewInit()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer the below link which explains different ways:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/3-ways-to-pass-async-data-to-angular-2-child-components

Answer (score 0):

Put a *ngIf to chid component to check if the data are received.
Child component will call only after data are received

```
<child-component *ngIf="data**strong text**" [myData]="data"></child-component>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes Finally I have Got The Proper sollution of this  .

Let's first create a basic component that will be nested in another component later on. This components has a title property that we use in its template:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-selector',
  template: 'child.component.html'
})
export class ChildComponent {  
  title = 'I\'m a nested component';
}
```

The child.component.html is just an HTML file that shows the value of the title property:

```
/* child.conponent.html */
<h2>{{title}}</h2>
```

Now we want to create a container component. It looks almost identical to the nested component, except we have to specify that we want to use the nested component. We do that by adding the ChildComponent to the directives property of the Component decorator. Without doing this, the ChildComponent can not be used.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-selector',
  template: 'parent.component.html',
  directives: [ChildComponent]
})
export class ParentComponent { }
```

The container component uses the nested component by specifying its directive in the template:

```
/* parent.component.html */
<div>  
  <h1>I'm a container component</h1>
  <child-selector></child-selector>
</div>
```

Passing data to a nested component

If a nested component wants to receive input from its container, it must expose a property to that container. The nested component exposes a property it can use to receive input from its container using the @Input decorator.

We use the Input decorator to decorate any property in the nested component class. This works with every property type, including objects. In our example, we'll pass a string value to the nested component's title property, so we'll mark that property with the @Input decorator:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-selector',
  template: 'child.component.html'
})
export class ChildComponent {  
  @Input() title:string;
}
```

Now our nested component is ready to receive input from its parent component.

In the container component, we need to define the property we want to pass to the nested component. We call it childTitle:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-selector',
  template: 'parent.component.html',
  directives: [ChildComponent]
})
export class ParentComponent {  

  childTitle:string = 'This text is passed to child';

 // you can assign data through web service also . 
}
```

Now the container component should pass the value of childTitle to the nested component by settings this property with property binding. When using property binding, we enclose the binding target in square brackets. The binding target refers to the title property of the nested component. We set the binding source to the data that the container wants to pass to the nested component, which is childTitle.

```
/* parent.component.html */
<div>  
  <h1>I'm a container component</h1>
  <child-selector [title]='childTitle'></child-selector>
</div>
```

The only time we can specify a nested component's property as a property binding target, is when that property is decorated with the @Input decorator, like we did earlier.

When we run our code, we should see the passed value in the nested component's H2 element

> ```
> OUTPUT : 
> I'm a container component
> This text is passed to child
> ```